# Why does the singular locus of a random rational curve always have the same Hilbert function?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

As background, let's first note that a random rational curve of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^n$ is smooth when $n\ge 3$. Indeed, picking a random rational curve of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^n$ corresponds to picking a $(n+1)$-dimensional subspace of $H^0(\mathcal O(d))$, which in turn corresponds to a choice of projection of the rational normal curve $C\subset \mathbb P^d$ to $\mathbb P^n$. When $n\ge 3$, this is usually a closed immersion (Hartshorne IV.3.5).

As Hal Schenck suggests in his book *Computational Algebraic Geometry*, one can verify this with a computer algebra system, say Macaulay2. I find that for $(d,n)=(4,3)$, one always obtains the following Hilbert function (starting in degree 0).

```
1 4 9 0 0 0 ...
```

Similarly, for $(d,n)=(5,3)$, we always get

```
1 4 10 16 4 0 0 0 ...
```

And for $(5,4)$, we always see

```
1 5 11 3 0 0 0 ...
```

So things are as they should be: the Hilbert polynomial is $0$, which means the singular locus is empty.

However, we have extra information in the form of these lower degree numbers, which are always the same. What explains them? Is there a way to determine what they will be for general $(d,n)$?

Here is the code I used to generate the curves (due to Schenck):

```
issmooth = (I)->(c = codim I;
J = jacobian mingens I;
minors(c,J)+I)
randratcurve = (d,n)->(R=ZZ/31991[s,t];
rands = random(R^{d}, R^(n+1));
S=ZZ/31991[a_0..a_n];
kernel map(R,S,rands))
iexamples = (i,d,n)->(
apply(i, j->(
slocus = issmooth(randratcurve(d,n));
apply({0,1,2,3,4,5,6}, j -> hilbertFunction(j,slocus)))))
```

Running `iexamples(i,d,n)` will give $i$ random examples with given $(d,n)$.

Edit: Some more experimentation suggests this boils down to a fact about the ideal defined by the minors of the Jacobian, whose Hilbert function also seems to depend only on $(d,n)$ and not the choice of curve (and is $0$ for large values). Of course, the Hilbert function of a $(d,n)$ curve can be determined by Riemann-Roch and the genus formula, and it seems plausible that if we can get at the Hilbert function coming from the Jacobian, we could relate the two (by an exact sequence?) and deduce the above result.

Edit 2: Another thought is that maybe we could show that the Hilbert function is independent of the choice of projection (I have in mind some kind of continuity argument) and then perform the computation for a particular choice of projection where life is simple.